# R: find rows meeting condition, sum value from next row and delete it

Tags: r

i am getting crazy trying to solve the following issue... Here is a simplified version of my data:

```
id <- c(1, 2, 2, 6, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10)
species <- c("a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "b")
number <- c(1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1)
facts <- c(5, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 8, 1, 4)

df <- data.frame(id, species, number, facts)
```

What I need to do is:

- identify the rows where (species == "a" & number == 2)
- add the value of facts from the next row to facts of the row that is meeting the condition
- delete the next row

The result would be:

```
  id species number facts
1  1       a      1     5
2  2       a      2     9
3  6       a      3     3
4  8       a      1     5
5  9       b      1     4
6  9       b      2     8
7  9       a      2     5
```

I have tried so many things that I don't know what approach to use anymore (if statements, apply functions, dplyr...), so far I have failed to produce any code worth posting here. I would be deeply ashamed... I also did not find any posts that relate. It is my first post here (really desperate) so I hope I described my problem correctly. Is there someone that can help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for rows where `species == "a" & facts == 2` or `species == "a" & number == 2`? From the expected output it looks you need `number == 2`.

Comment: You are right and very fast!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no rows where `species == "a" & facts == 2`. I think your condition is for `num = 2`

Here is one way with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(condition = cumsum(lag(!(species == 'a' & number == 2), default = TRUE))) %>%
  mutate(facts = sum(facts)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  distinct(condition, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(-condition)

#     id species number facts
#  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1 a            1     5
#2     2 a            2     9
#3     6 a            3     3
#4     8 a            1     5
#5     9 b            1     4
#6     9 b            2     8
#7     9 a            2     5
```

`condition` column is used to create groups so that rows 2 and 3 form one group and rows 8 and 9 another group. Rest of the rows are groups of only 1 row. We can take `sum` of each group and keep only unique rows in the group.

Answer (score 0):

Although not my favotite, you can solve it with a for loop

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
    
    if (df$species[i] == "a" & df$number[i] == 2){ #I supose you want rows with number == 2
        df$facts[i] <- df$facts[i] + df$facts[i+1]
        df$facts[i+1] <- NA
    }
}

df <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `dplyr` method.

```
df %>%
  mutate(facts = if_else(species == "a" & number == 2, dplyr::lead(facts, 1L) + facts, facts)) %>%
  filter(!lag(species == "a" & number == 2, 1L, F))
```